# Class defined in js file, undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bit of code like

```
var myClass = function(myArray) {
    this.arr = array;    
}
myClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
     //random code
};

module.exports = myClass;
```

When I start node from the console, require this file with `var a = require('./myClass.js')` and try to instantiate my class with

```
myclass = new myClass([1,2,3]);
```

what I get is `ReferenceError: myClass is not defined`. I am building a very small and easy game, I wonder how I would go about testing it and playing around with it from the node console. Thanks.

Comment: Show your require statement

Comment: Show us how are you importing that module. require statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
 var a = require('./myClass.js')
```

`a` becomes the thing you exported from 'myClass.js'. You would need to use it like:

```
var instance = new a([1, 2, 3])
```

You can do that, but it's probably easier to read and understand if you use a more descriptive variable name:

```
var myClass = require('./myClass.js')
// myClass is the function exported in `myClass.js`

var someInstance = new myClass([1,2,3]);
```

Also, you probably want to use `myArray` rather than `array` here:

```
var myClass = function(myArray) {
    this.arr = myArray // not array;    
}
```

Comment: Sure, the array bit was just a random thing i filled in. The problem was the require statement, I think I need to read seriously about how js works.